# Media background service was killed by system on Android 9 (Api 28)

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, background-service, android-9.0-pie

My media player running as background service **really well on** different Android versions (emulator and devices) :

- 5.1 (lollipop)
- 7.1.1 (Nougat)
- 8.1 (O)

**But on Android 9 (P) emulator**, after running in about 30 seconds,
my media player **suddenly stopped and screen is turned off**.

After turned screen on, i realize that my **media player background service was killed** by system already.

What I want is : my media player is still running well on Android P as Android L, Android N, Android O.

People who know how to fix this,

Please help me,

Thank you,

p/s :

I read some Docs but still not find out the way

- What changes in every [Version Codes] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#P)

[image]

Comment: [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

Comment: USe forground service

Comment: in particular read [Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) section